# How to create a grid view like this

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="13"
            >

            <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordGrid
                android:id="@+id/password_grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:columnCount="13">

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_2"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_3"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_4"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_6"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_7"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_8"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_9"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_10"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_11"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_12"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"

                    />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_13"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_14"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"

                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_15"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_16"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_17"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_18"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_19"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_20"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_21"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"

                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_22"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_23"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_24"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_25"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />

                <videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordButton
                    android:id="@+id/password_button_26"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/password_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/password_margin" />


  </videocon.vmat.activity.Touch.PasswordGrid>

</LinearLayout>
```

For phone screen size 4.7 inch ,it is displaying the grid view as in the image
but as the phone screen size varies this code is not displaying the grid view properly

Comment: use weight=1  with height 0dp in all `videocon Views`.... it is give you output same for all device .

Comment: @sushildlh not working